# Permutations And Combinations- Q. Ten balls numbered from $1$ to $10$.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Q. Ten balls numbered from $1$ to $10$ are to be put in three boxes numbered $1,2 ,$ and $3$ so that no box remains empty, then the number in which this can be so that ' Numbers of balls of box $1$ > Numbers of balls of box $2$ > Numbers of balls of box $3$ ' is -

My Attempt- I made these cases for each box-

NO. OF BALLS-

$1)        7  ,       2       ,   1;$

$2)        6   ,       3      ,    1;$

$3)        5   ,       4     ,     1;$

$4)        5    ,      3     ,     2;$

Then, I calculated the total no. of cases using Permutation , But my Answer is coming way larger than the original Answer! 
I Dont know where I am doing some mistake! Pls help!

Comment: Then what is your answer? Only by checking it we can find what you did wrong.

Comment: My Answer that is coming is 3090, however, the actual answer is just 36!

Comment: Is the ! a factorial or an exclamation?

Comment: Its just an exclamation.

Comment: I had Done correction in my Question, Actually The question wanted to say " The Number 'OF' Balls" instead of 'ON' . Now my Question should be clear, please unhold it!

Comment: Why is this so strict site? Sorry But I am closing my account! Majority of questions that are asked in this forum are closed or inhold ! Just because of different reasons you all make!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem has been interpreted to mean "number *of* balls in box 1..." whereas as phrased, it says "number*s* *on* balls".

Looking at the problem as written, the answer is $\binom{9}{2}=36$.

Imagine lining up the balls in reverse order: 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1. You can construct each placement satisfying your criteria if you place 2 "dividers" in 2 of the 9 gaps between the balls, like 10, 9, 8, |, 7, 6, 5,|, 4, 3, 2, 1, and put the balls before the first divider in box 1, the balls between the dividers in box 2, and the balls after the 2nd divider in box 3. (Check that you've satisfied your criteria). There are $\binom{9}{2}$ ways to place these dividers.

Comment: Thanks for help, I got that was printing error! Though it was an easy question.